# Which of the following query has the lowest cost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Which of the following query has the lowest cost?

A.

```
def recent_followers
  self.followers.recent.includes(:user).collect {|f| f.user.name }.to_sentence
end
```

B.

```
Select followers where user_id = 1

Select users where user_id in (2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: I suggest `https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler`. It'll show you the time each query took and a lot more useful information! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database querying is always faster, than Ruby processing.

Your first option uses `collect`, which has a disadvantage since it will have to load the whole collection into memory before processing.

You could rewrite your first try as:

```
followers.recent.joins(:user).pluck('users.name') # no need for self, btw
```